# Trace AccessLog on RewriteRule Activation

Tags: java, apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I need to configure a custom log on apache 2.4 (httpd) that trace all access intercepted by RewriteRule that I choose.

I hope you can help me, thanks